# What does node()|@* mean XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have seen this being used in this contect:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
```

Can anyone explain that the "node()|@*" means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called the [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying). The `node()|@*` is matching all child nodes (`node()`  is all text,element,processing instructions,comments) and attributes (`@*`) of the current context.

Comment: Well, more precisely, node() means child::node(), and @* means attribute::*, so it is matching all children and attributes of the context node. (It doesn't match document nodes or namespace nodes).

Comment: @MichaelKay - Yes you're right. I added a little clarification to my statment to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have wondered what it meant mean as i have used it in many XSL Docs without really understanding its functionality.

Comment: @Keevil - You're very welcome. The w3 has lots of good info about XSLT.

Comment: It's well worth trying to understand the Identity Transform. It's the key to many, many XSLT solutions. At a guess, about half my production stylesheets use it.

Comment: @Kevan - I'd say 99% of mine use it :-)